# Jquery Animation not happening on second click

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have created an animation that slides a div from the right side on click. It has a close button that retrieves it back to the original position. However I am not able to repeat that animation. ie., on Second click the animation is not working. Here is the jquery, I tried..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$elem1 = $('#myFirstElement');
$elem2 = $('#mySecondElement');
var scrollState = 'top';

$("#ongoing").toggle(function(){ 

    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

    if( ( scrollPos != 0 ) && ( scrollState === 'top' ) ) {
        $elem1.stop().animate({right: '+1px'}, 800);
             scrollState = 'scrolled';
    }       
    else if( ( scrollPos === 0 ) && ( scrollState === 'scrolled' ) ) {
         $elem1.stop().animate({right: '-=100%'}, 800);
        scrollState = 'top';
    }

});
});

</script>
```

Please advice how to resolve the issue.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle of same

Comment: the toggle function is supposed to return true or false, and that shows or hides #ongoing.  no animation should be happening there.  you say it's animating, but this code is only partial.  you have to post the html too.  I think you're looking at the wrong code if you think that part is working

Answer (score 0):

You need to use click event handler instead of using toggle method:

```
$("#ongoing").click(function(){
//             ^^ not toggle
```

As you are conditionally changing `scrollState`

Comment: I changed to Click . But the second time animation is not happening

Comment: Also note, `{right: '+1px'}` should be `{right: '+=1px'}`